# Cable becoming twisted

Tags: cables, mechanical

I was an audio technician and mobile DJ before retiring after 31 years of working, eight years ago. I NEVER coil any type of cable around my elbow, even household zipcord. Sometimes I do with cheap rope or twine, but that’s different.

I have a 100' 3-conductor 12 AWG power cable that I bought from Home Depot four years ago for yard work, that I always carefully coil after use.

A few months ago the last 20’ of it started coiling up like an old-school telephone receiver cord. It’s the only cable I’ve ever owned that’s done this. I have microphone, speaker, and power cables that I’ve had for 25 years that are perfectly fine. What’s the real reason that this happens and can I fix this cable?

[image]

Comment: Creep in the plastic I assume. Try dunking the just a small center portion of the cable cable in some very warm tap water (tap water that is too hot to touch, not boiling water) and see if it unstresses it. Not unlike how plastic skipping ropes develops bends in them when you bundle them up regardless of whether you are careful to not twist it while doing so.

Comment: Thanks.  I’ll try that too.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that there were stresses in the extruded (probably vinyl) plastic and it got hot allowing those stresses to be relieved (in the same way that a vinyl LP record or an injection-molded cafeteria tray would warp if left in a hot automobile).

If the cord insulation is intact I don't see that there's any need to fix it, but if you must try you could try heating it gently (no more than 60°C should be safe, but observe what is happening) and applying traction. The next time it gets hot in the sun it might go back though.

Comment: That makes sense.  Yeah, the insulation is still completely intact.  If it’ll be okay, I’ll probably leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with the picture, but a lot of times you can fix twisted cables with the help of gravity. Might be difficult with such a long cable, but you basically hold part of the cable (20' mark if you can find a high enough staircase) up while letting the end of the cable dangle freely and it'll usually untwist itself

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing there is called cable corkscrewing. This can be caused by the conductors shifting inside the jacket due to mechanical stress. One conductor having more tension can pull the side of the cable it's on shorter, causing it to twist.

The way the cable is constructed can make this more or less likely to happen. The way the conductors are arranged and the core used can reduce the likelihood of corkscrewing.

One thing that may have contributed to your cable twisting is the color. It appears to be one of the type that are orange with a black stripe. If this was left in the sun the black stripe could heat up more than the orange and cause that side of the jacket to expand more. This might explain why it only happened to 20 feet of one end, that end might have been on the outside of the rolled up cable where it would get the sun.

Comment: Would it help to cut the plug or socket off and replace it with a field-applied plug/socket?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Hard to say. Probably letting the cable hang with a bit of weight on it and gently heating would be the most likely thing to work. One problem with replacing the connector is whether the new connector will fit whatever this is being used to power, I had a weedwacker I used a cable like this on, where you plugged it in was just big enough for the molded plug to fit, I don't think they have replacement ones that small.

Comment: Oh, they make slim sockets now.  Yours may be the reason why!